# Search by 2 fields in a table from one textbox - c#

Tags: c#, ado.net

I want to get the details of the person whose full name I entered into the textbox. It works for me when I enter a first name only.
 Maybe I did not write the like statement right? I do not remember the subject so much.

### Thanks in advance

```
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dv.RowFilter = "DocFirstName+' '+DocLastName like '" + textBox1.Text + "%'";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one word first name and one word last name, you can use `or`:

```
var split = textBox1.Text.Split();
var FirstName = split[0];

string condition = String.Format("DocFirstName Like '%{0}%' ", split[0]);

if(split.Length > 1)
  condition += String.Format("or DocLastName = '%{0}%'", split[1]);

dv.RowFilter = condition;
```

You can easily alter this if you want to treat each value as a possible `FirstName` and `LastName` at the same time.